# How can I disable Windows 8 Fast Boot if I don't have Windows 8?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7, windows-8, uefi

I've been searching around for this for a while, but I haven't found anyone else with the same problem.  Guess no one made the same stupid mistake.

I have a Windows 7/Ubuntu computer that is suffering from Windows 8 Fast Boot.  I can see how this might be an uncommon problem to have, so I've written out how I managed to get myself into this predicament below.

I'm on an Alienware 14 that originally had *Windows 7*.  I installed a second hard drive and got Ubuntu working on it no problem.  I didn't think I touched the original hard drive at all, but when I was done, Windows was refusing to boot.  I tried to fix it and eventually gave up.  It wasn't a big deal.  All my stuff was backed up for that reason anyway.  So then, I tried to reinstall Windows from a recovery USB key I have by going through the BIOS boot menu, but the computer wouldn't boot from the recovery flash drive unless I picked the UEFI option.  I went ahead and reinstalled using the UEFI option and Windows was working fine again, so I thought "this is great!"  I then went back into BIOS and disabled the Legacy ROM thing.  An option for Windows 8 Fast Boot was now available and enabled by default.  I turned it off because I didn't want it, but then turned it on again later, not realizing it would cause great harm.

Now, through a great series of steps, I have Ubuntu installed on the first hard drive rather than the second (which is not a problem) and a Windows 7 installation that can't boot or repair or do *anything* on the second.  I want to reinstall this Windows 7, but I have no way to access BIOS or EFI or whatever the correct term is.  Because of the enabled Windows 8 Fast Boot, there is no option to enter BIOS on startup, and I don't have Windows 8 to turn off the setting.  I've tried pulling my laptop completely apart to unplug the CMOS battery.  That didn't work.  It still doesn't let me get to my BIOS on startup.

Comment: Usually there is a service key or shortcut that resets the BIOS/UEFI to defaults, e.g. hold [PageUp] while switching the power on. You could maybe google whether such a key is existing for your machine or UEFI.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/13326-downgrade-windows-8-windows-7-a.html)

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!  I don't know what happened, but some combination of holding delete and messing with the recovery flash drive allowed me to get into the BIOS.  Not sure how, but Fast Boot is now OFF.  THANK YOU!!

Comment: @ByteCommander: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: @Fabby Converted!

Answer (score 0):

Usually there is a service key or shortcut that resets the BIOS/UEFI to defaults, e.g. hold <kbd>PgUp</kbd> while switching the power on. You could maybe google whether such a key is existing for your machine or UEFI.

Once that is done, you will be able to access the BIOS again!